# Accessing a file on the server's hard drive

Tags: javascript, file, html, local

I have a webpage that needs to read a status file on the webserver hosting the page. The file is on the hard drive of the webserver just not under inetpub/wwwroot/... I know how to access the file if it is in the same directory as the webpage but not if it is in a different directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use a server side script to check the status and call that script using Ajax.

Comment: This might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732881/write-to-text-file-outside-of-webroot-directory

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reach the file that is "above" the wwwroot folder by design. The way to do this is to a) copy the file there, b) setup a symbolic link (if on linux) or c) preferably, move / setup another web root folder.

Alternatively, write a server script to dump the file contents.